# Java login with MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, authentication

Hi at the moment I can't log in to MySQL database with SQL statement and open next MenuForm. Not sure what's wrong with it. There is no error. I have added additional if "//if(password.contains("123") && username.contains("test")) {" to check if it works and it does work but still can't compare it with MySQL.

```
private void jButton_LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

       PreparedStatement st;
       ResultSet rs;

       // get the username & password
       String username = jTextField_Username.getText();
       String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword());

       //create a select query to check if the username and the password exist in the database
       String query = "SELECT * FROM users_db.users WHERE 'username' = ? and 'password' = ?";

        try {
            st = My_CNX.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);


            st.setString(1, username);
            st.setString(2, password);
            rs = st.executeQuery();

            //if(password.contains("123") && username.contains("test")) {
            if(rs.next()){
                // show a new form
                MenuForm form = new MenuForm();
                form.setVisible(true);
                form.pack(); // rozmiarem ma się zająć automatycznie manager rozmiaru? druga opcja to ustalenie romziaru x i y, za pomocą innej funkcji
                form.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                //close the current form(login form)
                form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.dispose();

            }else{
            // error message

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password", "Login Error",2);

        }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }
```

I have added whole code here.
I have included the whole login Form below.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Login_register_design;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;




/**
 *
 * @author tomas
 */
public class Login_Form extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Login_Form
     */
    public Login_Form() {
        initComponents();
        /* - Downalod The Connector For Java & MySQL database*/ 
        /* Link -> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ */

        /* OPEN */
        /*Create a connection with the database */

        // Center the form
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
       // create a yellow border for the panel_title
       // 0 border in the top
       Border jpanel_title_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.blue);
       // set the border to the jpanel_title
       jPanel_title.setBorder(jpanel_title_border);

       // create a orange border for the global panel
       Border global_panel_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.orange);
       jPanel5.setBorder(global_panel_border);

       // create a black border for the close & minimize jlables
       Border label_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.black);
       jLabel_minimize.setBorder(label_border);
       jLabel_close.setBorder(label_border);

       // create border for the username and password field
       Border field_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 5, 1, 1, Color.white);
       jTextField_Username.setBorder(field_border);
       jPasswordField.setBorder(field_border);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel_username = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel_password = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField_Username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButton_Login = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel_minimize = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel_close = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel_title = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 153));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 462, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 330, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));

        jLabel_username.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/grafika/Loginemail-100px.png"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel_password.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/grafika/Hasło-100px.png"))); // NOI18N

        jTextField_Username.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTextField_Username.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
        jTextField_Username.setText("username");
        jTextField_Username.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jTextField_UsernameFocusGained(evt);
            }
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jTextField_UsernameFocusLost(evt);
            }
        });
        jTextField_Username.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField_UsernameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPasswordField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jPasswordField.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
        jPasswordField.setText("password");
        jPasswordField.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jPasswordFieldFocusGained(evt);
            }
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jPasswordFieldFocusLost(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton_Login.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 84, 140));
        jButton_Login.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jButton_Login.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton_Login.setText("Login");
        jButton_Login.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jButton_Login.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton_LoginMouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton_LoginMouseExited(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton_Login.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton_LoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jButton_Login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 382, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel_password)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPasswordField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 278, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel_username)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField_Username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 279, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(174, 174, 174)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField_Username)
                    .addComponent(jLabel_username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel_password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton_Login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        // set icon to the jlabel
        // set icon to the jlabel

        jLabel_minimize.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel_minimize.setText("-");
        jLabel_minimize.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jLabel_minimize.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(17, 29));
        jLabel_minimize.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel_minimizeMouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel_minimizeMouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel_minimizeMouseExited(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel_close.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel_close.setText("X");
        jLabel_close.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jLabel_close.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel_closeMouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel_closeMouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel_closeMouseExited(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel_title.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 153, 255));

        jLabel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 153, 255));
        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("Login");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel_titleLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel_title);
        jPanel_title.setLayout(jPanel_titleLayout);
        jPanel_titleLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel_titleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel_titleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addContainerGap(42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel_titleLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel_titleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel_titleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(118, 118, 118)
                        .addComponent(jPanel_title, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                        .addComponent(jLabel_minimize, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel_close))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                        .addComponent(jPanel_title, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel_close)
                            .addComponent(jLabel_minimize, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
        jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
        jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jLabel_minimizeMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             

       Border label_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.white);
       jLabel_minimize.setBorder(label_border);
       jLabel_minimize.setForeground(Color.white);

    }                                            

    private void jLabel_minimizeMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            

        Border label_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.black);
        jLabel_minimize.setBorder(label_border);
        jLabel_minimize.setForeground(Color.black);
    }                                           

    private void jLabel_closeMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

       Border label_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.white);
       jLabel_close.setBorder(label_border);
       jLabel_close.setForeground(Color.white);    
    }                                         

    private void jLabel_closeMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

       Border label_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.black);
       jLabel_close.setBorder(label_border);
       jLabel_close.setForeground(Color.black);

    }                                        

    private void jTextField_UsernameFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                                

        // clear the testfield on focus if the text is "username"
        if(jTextField_Username.getText().trim().toLowerCase().equals("username"));
        {
            jTextField_Username.setText("");
            jTextField_Username.setForeground(Color.black);
        }


         Border jpanel_icon = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.blue);

        jLabel_username.setBorder(jpanel_icon);

    }                                               

    private void jTextField_UsernameFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                              

        // if the text field is equal to username or empty
        // we will set the "username" text in the field on
        // on focus lost event

        if(jTextField_Username.getText().trim().equals("") ||
           jTextField_Username.getText().trim().toLowerCase().equals("username"))
        {
           jTextField_Username.setText("username");
           jTextField_Username.setForeground(new Color(153,153,153));
        }
         // create a border with the color of the parent jpanel for the icons label to remove the move
       Border label_icons_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(153,153,153));
       jLabel_username.setBorder(label_icons_border);
    }                                             

    private void jPasswordFieldFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                           

        // clear the password on focus if the text is "password"
        // get the password text
        String pass = String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword());

        if(pass.trim().toLowerCase().equals("password"));
        {
            jPasswordField.setText("");
            jPasswordField.setForeground(Color.black);
        }

        // set a yellow border to the jlabel icon
         Border jpanel_icon = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.blue);
       // set the border to the jpanel_title
        jLabel_password.setBorder(jpanel_icon);

    }                                          

    private void jPasswordFieldFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                         


           // get the password text
        String pass = String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword());

        if(pass.trim().equals("") ||
           pass.trim().toLowerCase().equals("password"))
        {
           jPasswordField.setText("password");
           jPasswordField.setForeground(new Color(153,153,153));
        }

         // create a border with the color of the parent jpanel for the icons label to remove the move
       Border label_icons_border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(153,153,153));
       jLabel_password.setBorder(label_icons_border);  
    }                                        

    private void jButton_LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

       PreparedStatement st;
       ResultSet rs;

       // get the username & password
       String username = jTextField_Username.getText();
       String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword());

       //create a select query to check if the username and the password exist in the database
       String query = "SELECT * FROM users_db.users WHERE 'username' = ? and 'password' = ?";

        try {
            st = My_CNX.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);


            st.setString(1, username);
            st.setString(2, password);
            rs = st.executeQuery();

            //if(password.contains("123") && username.contains("test")) {
            if(rs.next()){
                // show a new form
                MenuForm form = new MenuForm();
                form.setVisible(true);
                form.pack(); // rozmiarem ma się zająć automatycznie manager rozmiaru? druga opcja to ustalenie romziaru x i y, za pomocą innej funkcji
                form.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                //close the current form(login form)
                form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.dispose();

            }else{
            // error message

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username or Password", "Login Error",2);

        }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }                                             

    private void jButton_LoginMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           

         //set jbutton backbround
        jButton_Login.setBackground(new Color(0, 101, 183));


    }                                          

    private void jButton_LoginMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

        //set jbutton backbround
        jButton_Login.setBackground(new Color(0, 84, 104));

    }                                         

    private void jLabel_minimizeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             

        this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);

    }                                            

    private void jLabel_closeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

        System.exit(0);

    }                                         

    private void jTextField_UsernameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login_Form().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Login;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_close;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_minimize;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_password;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel_username;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_title;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField_Username;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Storing passwords in clear-text is a no-go for security reasons. You should consider storing only hash codes, like Mysql itself does in the table ```mysql.user```. They "why" and "how else" is explained there: https://itnext.io/how-not-to-store-passwords-4955569e6e84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
"SELECT * FROM users_db.users WHERE 'username' = ? and 'password' = ?"
```

with

```
"SELECT * FROM users_db.users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"
```

Note that I have removed single quotes enclosing fields.